# After rooting my verizon Galaxy S3, I have no data or cellular connection?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-connection, network-signal

So, when I first rooted my phone, everything worked fine. I had used CM 10.1 (Or at least some version of Cyanogenmod). Being curious, I wanted to try other ROMs. I then installed MUIU v5. Didn't like so I went back to a backup I had created previously, and updated to the latest version of Cyanogenmod. When I go to Settings->About Phone->Status, I see these settings:

```
Network: Verizon Wireless
Signal Strength: -97 dBm 1 asu
Mobile network type: CDMA - 1xRTT:7
Service State: In service
Roaming: Roaming
Mobile network state: Disconnected
My phone number: ***-***-****   --Giberish which ISN'T my phone number
MIN, MEID, IMEI, ICCID all give me long numbers.
IP Address: Unavailable
```

This is when Airplane Mode is off. My little signal icon in the top status bar has an R which I'm guessing is for Roaming.

I have no idea why it's doing this seeing that it worked fine before on Cyanogenmod. What can I do to get my signal and data connection back? What would have caused something like this?

Comment: Under settings -> more... -> Mobile networks verify that "CDMA Subscription" is set to "RUIM/SIM"

Comment: @dymmeh and what do i do if it is or isn't there?

Comment: If it's not set to "RUIM/SIM" change it to that.